# forgot to turn on crock pot for less than 2 hours

Tags: kitchen-safety

I left a pork roast in my crock pot for a little less than 2 hours, but forgot to turn crock pot on.  It still felt cool to the touch.  Is it safe to eat?

Answer (score 0):

When these things happen (and you're still within 2 hrs), you want to get everything heated up as quickly as possible, so it's out of the food danger zone.

See my notes at the bottom of an answer on [prepping things the night before](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/49369/67) on heating things up faster.